# Angular Render link

Tags: angular, typescript, components, ag-grid

I am using a library called `ag-grid` which allows me to create a table of data. In this table, I am including a link to a user profile via a `routerLink`.

My problem is that if the user is invalid in the search, the link would take you to an invalid profile so I am trying to use a different link for that situation.

I created a component that is generating the link like I need it but its just printing the HTML to the page.

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: "{{ link }}"
})

export class ViewLinkComponent {

  params: any;
  link: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {

    this.params = params;

    // If we don't have an NTID, we can assume this is an invalid record
    if (this.params.data.QID == '-') {

      // Loop over our data object
      for (var key in this.params.data) {

        if (this.params.data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          // If we are not looking at order and our values are not empty
          if (key != 'order' && this.params.data[key] != '-') {
            this.link = this.createLink(this.params.data[key]);
            return;
          }

        }

      }

    }else{
      this.link = '<a routerLink="/profile/'+ params.data.NTID +'">View Profile</a>'
    }

  }

  createLink(query){
    return '<a href="https://external.com/search?q='+query+'" target="_blank">Search</a>';
  }

}
```

**End Result:**

The below image is showing the correct link, but not rendering it as an actual clickable link.

[image]

However, if I were to do the following it renders fine:

```
@Component({
  template: "<a routerLink='/profile/{{ params.data.NTID }}'>View Profile</a>"
})
```

Problem with this is that I need to use some logic to determine if its an internal link using a route or an external link.

Is there a way for me to tell this component that its okay to render that HTML, assuming its a security thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way to generate native HTML code is [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2). However, `RouterLink` is a directive, it won't be taken in account if you generate your link at runtime.
You cannot bypass conditional templating like this:

```
<a *ngIf="isUserValid" routerLink="/profile/...
<a *ngIf="!isUserValid" href="https://external.com/search...
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about using an `ngIf` to have both sets of logic. This helped me with my problem.